# C# windows forms: Relative position of growing elements c# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, datagridview, position

I have some problem with resizing of [`DataGridView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx).

I have three different `DataGridView` and I want to resize them with window and I need to keep it the same size, and to keep their relative position the same.
Screenshots of that what I've done:

Layout that I want:

[image]

How it is now:

[image]

Problem now is that, when I set e.g. for middle data grid anchors on top/left/right/bot that's not moving and at the same time, top data grid is growing. I tried many settings and cannot find the correct one.
Thanks in advance!

Settings now:

- top `DataGridView`, anchor top/left/right/bot
- middle `DataGridView`, anchor bot/left/right
- bottom `DataGridView`, anchor bot

Comment: Anchor all three of them to Top, Left, Bottom, Right and let me know if that sorts your issue

Comment: As I wrote above - that's not moving grids, only resizing, result is that half of grids/buttons are not visible or covered by other one.  Aditionally I think that cannot grow with anchors, because of three big growing elements - that have to share their sizes to each other. I hope u know what I mean

Comment: @DavidWatts The reason that doesn't work is because each `DataGridView` will increase at the same rate as the form.  When you have 3 of them the total increase in size is 3 times the form's increase.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted (check box) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `TableLayoutPanel` with 3 rows.  Set the height of each row to 33%.  Place a `Panel` in each row and put your controls in the `Panels` (`TableLayoutPanels` only allow one control per cell).

Set the `Dock` value to `Fill` for each `Panel` and then set the `Anchor` for each `DataGridView` to `Top, Left, Bottom, Right`.

Set the `Anchor` for the `TableLayoutPanel` to  `Top, Left, Bottom, Right` OR set the `Dock` to `Fill`

Comment: With some small changes it works perfectly for me, TableLayout makes everything clear and easy! Thanks a lot ;)